# Google Ads probability

Tags: probability

In Google search results, we have two options of showing Ads: 1. show one Ad every 25 results; 2. there is 4% probability to show one Ad after every result. Which option is better for the advertiser? Let's assume people will look at 100 results.

Comment: option 3: not using Google Ads

Comment: How many ads do you get to show after 25 results?

Comment: Better for who?

Comment: People rarely scroll down beyond the first 10 results or so.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the problem to avoid these confusions.

Comment: In Option 1: Would the first ad shown be after Result $1$, Result $25$ or somewhere in between?

Comment: After result 25

Comment: Calculate the expected value of the number of ads after 100 trials. It is a binomial distribution.

Comment: Could you define the goal of the advertiser? Some answers dive into the number of times the ad gets shown, but it is not clear to me that is a correct approach. Note that the advertiser only pays Google when people click on their ads, so fewer ads shown means less money wasted on Google.

Comment: Why did you remove all the content from the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assume people look at $N$ results. If we take option 1, the number of ads displayed is $\lfloor N/25\rfloor$.

If we take option 2, the number of ads is a random variable which follows the binomial distribution with $N$ trials and probability $0.04$. Its expected value is $0.04\cdot N$.

If $N=100$, then $0.04\cdot100=\lfloor 100/25\rfloor$, so the options are the same on average. However, if $N$ is not a multiple of 25, option 2 display more ads on average. For example, if $N=49$, then option 1 displays $1$ ad, while option 2 will display on average $0.04\cdot49=1.96$ ads (most likely it will display 2 ads).

Therefore option $2$ is better since it displays on average at least as many ads at option 1. However, the margin is very small. To improve option 1, you can display 1 ad at the beginning of every page, then another ad for each 25 results. Then the formula becomes $1+\lfloor N/25\rfloor$, and this will make option 1 better on average.

Answer (score 0):

With the first option you'll see $4$ adds after $100$ searches. 
With the second option the expected number of adds after doing $100$ searches is $4$% of $100$, namely $4$, so same thing.